# Can no longer stay on my home page

Tags: page-viewer-web-part

As soon as I reach the home page of the S/P website I am immediately getting redirected to the page viewer web part address (internet address). I'd like now to get rid of this page viewer (don't really need it) but need to be able to stay on the home page, edit it, and finally remove the page viewer web part. Can you help?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the page in [web part maintenance mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-and-use-the-Web-Part-Maintenance-Page-eff9ce22-d04a-44dd-ae83-ac29a5e396c2).

> To access the Web Part Maintenance Page for a page that is not stored
>   in a document library, such as the site home page, append ?Contents=1
>   to the end of the URL for the page.

Then delete the webpart in question.